# How to include headers with my Patch request - authorized buyers 1.4

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Ran into a similar problem as this question from 2014:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-doubleclick-ad-exchange-buyer-api/blacklist%7Csort:date/google-doubleclick-ad-exchange-buyer-api/cygoU_pWUos/f72eHju3AIQJ

When trying to patch my pretargeting config I got the following alert:
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError 413 when requesting...returned "Request Too Large"

I think this is due to the size of the blacklist I am trying to add as excludedPlacements.  I can confirm my code works with a smaller array, which leads credence to my theory that it's the size of my blacklist.

To reduce the size of the body of my request, I'm attempting to gzip the body, but I'm stuck using the AdExchange Buyer api and I can't figure out how to include a header with my request to declare my encoding.  The patch method only has args for accountId and configId

How can I include headers to my request to Google, below is my code:

Alternatively, is there a better way to reduce the payload of my request to avoid using gzip?

I tried passing the headers into an http request by using the requestBuilder (one of the args for the Google api construct), but wasn't able to get this to work

```py
buyer_service = build('adexchangebuyer', VERSION, credentials=credentials)

request = buyer_service.pretargetingConfig().patch(accountId=ACCOUNT_ID, configId=CONFIG_NAME,body=BODY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to include headers, you need to avoid their api build and instead authorise an http request as follows, using your client secrets credentials:

from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
response = authed_session.patch(url=URL, headers=headers, data=gzipBODY)